# Use Differentiability of a Power Series to find the sum S(x)=$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2 n}}{n}$

Tags: calculus

The question states:

> Use Differentiability of a Power Series to find the sum S(x)=$\sum _{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2 n}}{n}$ in the form of an elementary function within the radius of convergence of S(x).

I have no clue where to start, and what I even need to do with the problem... Any help please?

Comment: What happens if you differentiate $S$????????????????????????????

Comment: I would get s'(x)=(2x^(2n-1))

Comment: Hopefully you mean the sum over $n=1$ to $\infty$. What would that sum be?

Comment: Do you mean the sum of s'(x)? If yes, then it would give something like 2x+2x^3+2x^5+...

Comment: Perhaps you could look at the geometric series and compute a closed form?

Answer (score 1):

$S'(x)=2x+2x^3+2x^5+\dots=2x\cdot \sum_{n\ge0}(x^2)^n=2x/(1-x^2)$ for $\mid x\mid\lt1$.

And $S(0)=0$.

So $S(x)=\int 2x/(1-x^2)\operatorname dx=-\ln(1-x^2)+C$.  And $C=0$.

You may recognize the power series for $\ln(1+x)$.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I know what this is asking. Here are some steps:

Differentiate all terms in S(x), such that,

S(x) = x^2 + x^4/2 + x^6/3 +....

S'(x) = 2x + 2x^3 + 2x^5 + .....

Notice that you can divide everything by 2 such that

1/2*S'(x) = x + x^3 + x^5 + .....

And you can divide everything by 2x such that

1/2x*S'(x) = 1 + x^2 + x^4 + ....

Thus,

1/2x*S'(x) + 1/2*S'(x) = 1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + ..... = 1/(1-x)

(1+x)/2x*S'(x) = 1/(1-x)

S'(x) = (2x)/(1-x)(1+x)

Now just find the anti derivative to find S(x). Note that this works because we got everything in the form of a known Taylor series, in this case 1/1-x. Also remember that Taylor Series has a radius of convergence of 1, or (-1, 1). Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes I am sure, the problem is with just n in the denominator.

Comment: Sweet, just updated it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution, it makes sense! The only thing I don't understand is the before last line of your solution... After you figure out that 1/2x(S'(x))+1/2(S'(x)) = geometric series. How do you get to (1+x)/2x*S'(x) = 1/(1-x)?

Comment: I just multiplied 1/2*(S'(x)) by x/x so that it had the same denominator as 1/2x*(S'(x)) so I could add them together.